# Closed form for the A347205

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, closed-form-expressions

Let $q(n)$ be [A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814), i.e., number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $n$. Here
$$q(2n+1)=0, q(2n)=q(n)+1$$

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120), i.e., number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$). Here
$$\operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1,\operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n),\operatorname{wt}(0)=0$$

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$

Let $f(n)$ be [A054429](https://oeis.org/A054429), i.e., simple self-inverse permutation of natural numbers: list each block of $2^n$ numbers (from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1} - 1$) in reverse order. Here
$$f(n)=3\cdot2^{\ell(n)}-n-1$$

Let
$$g(n,m)=2(f(n+2^{\ell(n)+1})+2^{\ell(n)+2}(2^m-1))$$

Let $h(n)$ be [A059893](https://oeis.org/A059893), i.e., reverse the order of all but the most significant bit in binary expansion of $n$: if $n = 1ab\cdots yz$ then $h(n) = 1zy\cdots ba$.

Let $a(n)$ be [A347205](http://oeis.org/A347205). Here
$$a(2n+1)=a(n), a(2n)=a(n)+a(n-2^{q(n)}), a(0)=1$$

Let $T(n,k)$ be an integer coefficients described in [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437447/closed-form-for-the-sum-of-the-integer-coefficients).

I conjecture that
$$a(g(n,m))=\frac{1}{(\operatorname{wt}(n)+1)!}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\operatorname{wt}(n)+2}(m+1)^{k-1}T(h(n),\operatorname{wt}(n)-k+3)$$

Is there a way to prove it?